# Adding --help for Docker image

Tags: docker

Is there a way to add a --help message to a docker image that can be displayed when running from the command line? I haven't been able to find anything online or in the docker docs.

Comment: Not that I know. But there is a simple workaround : if you want to display a message to users on how using your image, what i've done sometimes was to add an ENTRYPOINT to echo a help.txt message. This might be not the best way but this helped users many times

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in the entrypoint as mentioned by @Yazou, I am adding entrypoint in Dockerfile, you can create separate file as well.

This will `log` help message if container started with `--help` CMD otherwise it will start the desired process.

```
FROM alpine

RUN echo $'#!/bin/sh \n\ 
      echo "to see image helo run docker with --help" \n\
      if [ "${1}" == "--help" ]; then \n\
      echo "docker run -it --rm my_app argument1 argument1" \n\
      echo "my_app --option etc" \n\
      else \n\
      exec "$@" \n\
      fi \n\
     ' >> /bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /bin/entrypoint.sh

entrypoint ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

To test `--help` flag

```
docker run -it my_image --help
```

output

```
to see image helo run docker with --help
docker run -it --rm my_app argument1 argument1
my_app --option etc
```

without `--help` flag

```
docker run -it my_image
```

output

```
to see image helo run docker with --help
```